# Using single windows service to host 4 different WCF projects. How?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

Have above 5 WCF projects. In which 4 has to be hosted as windows service and 1 in IIS. All in the same machine.

For each of the 4 WCF projects, I require 4 Windows service projects to host separately. To minimize the number of projects to be maintained, I am thinking of one single windows service to install all the 4 WCF projects for easy maintainability. Anyway apart from OnStart and OnStop I call the wcf and no other logics are there.

The challenges I see are, each Windows service requires the same app config file as used in WCF projects. If I would do this dynamically by getting the service name from app settings, How will I load the app.config file of different wcf projects to host as windows service during run time.

Is this feasible ? If so how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, you just need to configure each one endpoint in your config file. How to do that:

1. Windows Service WCF hoster is [ServiceHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.servicehost?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class, so you need to create 4 hosts for every contract.

   var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CommunicationManagement));
   serviceHost.Open()
2. Now you can configure every your service endpoint in services section:

```html
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
 <service name="Communication.Service.CommunicationManagement">
  <endpoint
    binding="netTcpBinding" 
     bindingConfiguration="myBinding" 
     contract="Communication.Service.ICommunicationManagement" 
     name="CommunicationManagement">
   <identity>
    <dns value="localhost" />
   </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="MEX" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  <host>
   <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/Communication/Service/CommunicationManagement" />
   </baseAddresses>
  </host>
 </service>
 <service bname="Communication.Service.Managers.PhoneAdatpersManager">
  <endpoint 
    binding="netTcpBinding"
     bindingConfiguration="myBinding" 
     contract="Communication.IPhoneAdministration"
     name="PhoneAdministration">
   <identity>
    <dns value="localhost" />
   </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="MEX" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  <host>
   <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/Communication/Service/PhoneAdministration" />
   </baseAddresses>
  </host>
 </service>
</services>
<system.serviceModel>
```

3. Above you can see `PhoneAdatpersManager` and `CommunicationManagement` services, they hosting in a single Windows Service and works together on 8000 port (but you can use different ports).